# Justifying text in theorems environments in beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, theorems

I am trying to get justify text not only in blocks and frames but also in theorem blocks. I try two codes:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
```

and

```
\apptocmd{\block}{}{\justifying}{}
```

Neither works.

Some ideas please?

Here is my mwe

```
\documentclass[envcountsect,usenames,x11names,svgnames,spanish]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl,aeguill}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % For justifying text


\definecolor{bluepigment}{rgb}{0.25, 0.25, 0.5}
\makeatletter
\def\th@definition{%
\itshape % body font
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=bluepigment,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=bluepigment!25,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=bluepigment}
\def\inserttheoremblockenv{exampleblock}
  }
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definicion}{Definición}[section]% Definition


\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % Allow optional arguments after frame.


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{definicion}[Lipsum text]

\lipsum[2]

\end{definicion}

\end{frame}
```

PD: I need `etoolbox` package for the sentence

```
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}
```

but in other beamers I used this order without the package. Is it loaded by other packages???

Thanks

Comment: `\usepackage{etoolbox}` is only necessary in old beamer versions - with the current versions the package is already loaded by beamer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do `\addtobeamertemplate{theorem begin}{}{\justifying}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % For justifying text

\definecolor{bluepigment}{rgb}{0.25, 0.25, 0.5}
\makeatletter
\def\th@definition{%
    \itshape % body font
    \setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=bluepigment,fg=white}
    \setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=bluepigment!25,fg=black}
    \setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=bluepigment}
    \def\inserttheoremblockenv{exampleblock}
}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definicion}{Definición}[section]% Definition

\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % Allow optional arguments after frame.

\addtobeamertemplate{theorem begin}{}{\justifying}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \lipsum[2]

    \begin{definicion}[Lipsum text]
    \lipsum[2]
    \end{definicion}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]